# How can I short circuit my own andmap function?

Tags: racket

I have:

```
(define (andmap1 pred lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst)true]
    [(pred (first lst)) (andmap1 pred (rest lst))]
    [else false]))
```

For

```
(andmap1 positive? (list 1 1 2))
```

```
(andmap1 positive? (list 1 -1 2))
```

I get the correct answer.

However when I put in:

```
(andmap1 positive? (list "Hi" 1))
```

```
(andmap1 positive? (list 'Hi 1))
```

```
(andmap1 positive? (list false 1))
```

I get an error.
How can I make the function stop if there is a mismatch between pred and an element in the list? (pred can be any predicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can't: handling errors will solve *some* of the problem but not all of it.  The reason you can't is pretty important.  In order to be able to stop before calling the procedure on an argument you have to be able to answer two questions:

- will this procedure, with this argument, raise an exception of some kind?
- will this procedure, with this argument, fail to terminate?

Where, as you said, the procedure can be any procedure at all.  If the first is true, then if you can handle errors, you can deal with the problem.  But if the second is true this does not help you.

Those questions, famously, [can't be answered](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/%7Egpullum/loopsnoop.html) (this link isn't, obviously, the original proof of this, but it's a lovely description).

Your best hope, if you already know that there are some arguments your predicate doesn't like, is to wrap it in some kind of guard which will cause it to fail on those.  You can either do that by just passing a different predicate which explicitly checks, or you could provide an optional 'guard' predicate:

```
(define (andmap1 pred lst #:guard (guard #f))
  (define effective-pred
    (if guard
        (λ (x)
          (and (guard x) (pred x)))
        pred))
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) true]
    [(effective-pred (first lst))
     (andmap1 effective-pred (rest lst))]
    [else false]))
```

Now `(andmap1 positive? '(1 2 3 "x"))` will raise an error, but `(andmap1 positive '(1 2 3 "x") #:guard integer?)` will just return `#f`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `andmap1` is fine and is short-circuiting already.

```
> (andmap1 positive? (list -1 "Hi"))
#f
```

The meaning of short-circuit here is that, if `x` is an element before `y` in the list, and `(p x)` evaluates to false, then `(p y)` will not be evaluated. In my example above, `(positive? "Hi")` is not evaluated, because `(p -1)` already evaluates to false.

For your example, `(positive? "Hi")` is evaluated, because there is no element before `"Hi"` that, when applied to `positive?`, returns false. And because the contract for `positive?` is `number? -> number?`, you got a contract violation error (since `"Hi"` is not a number).

But what if you want something like `(andmap1 positive? (list "Hi" 1))` to work without causing an error?

One possibility is to relax `positive?` so that it doesn't cause a contract violation error.

```
;; my-positive? :: any/c -> boolean?
(define (my-positive? x)
  (and (number? x) (positive? x)))

> (my-positive? "Hi")
#f
> (my-positive? -1)
#f
> (my-positive? 1)
#t
```

Then:

```
> (andmap1 my-positive? (list "Hi" 1))
#f
```

Another possibility is to handle errors in your `andmap1`:

```
(define (andmap1 pred lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) true]
    [else 
     (with-handlers ([exn:fail? (lambda (e) #f)])
       (cond
         [(pred (first lst)) (andmap1 pred (rest lst))]
         [else false]))]))

> (andmap1 positive? (list "Hi" 1))
#f
```